# Движение картинки по вертикали и отражение от стенок

Tags: javascript, анимация, позиционирование

При нажатии на кнопку должен появляться `img` и двигаться по вертикали отражаясь от стенок. Проблема в том, что двигаться он не хочет.
Чувствую, что истина  где-то рядом, но не понимаю, что сделать, чтоб заработало. 
P.S. Извините, за полотно кода и если ошибка тупая, только учусь

```js
var but = document.getElementById('but');

but.onclick = function() {
  dx = 2;
  var img_ball = document.createElement('img');
  img_ball.src = "ball.jpg";
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(img_ball);
  img_ball.style.width = "60px";
  img_ball.style.height = "60px";
  img_ball.style.position = "absolute";
  img_ball.style.left = "0px";
  img_ball.style.bottom = "0px";
  mostRight = document.body.clientWidth;
  myBall = img_ball.style;
  mostRight -= ballWidth;
  setInterval('Move()', 42);
}

function Move() {
  var left = parseInt(myBall.left);
  var newLeft = left + dx;
  if (newLeft < 0 || newLeft >= mostRight) {
    dx = -dx;
    newLeft = left + dx;
  }
  myBall.left = newLeft;

}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#but {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -50px;
  padding: 20px 50px;
  border: none;
  background: #FF8C00;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#but:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 4px solid black;
}

#but:active {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="but">Create</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не стал исправлять ваш вариант...Вот, на коленках накидал...
А вообще, если это весь код, то вам нужно подробнее ознакомиться с понятиями "переменная", как она объявляется и область видимости переменной. Ведь функция `Move`, не видит то, что вы объявили в обработчики клика.
Еще вы пишите в заголовки движение по вертикали, а оперируете значениями `left` и `right` это же горизонталь не так ли?

```js
let images = [];
document.getElementById('but').onclick = () => {
  const img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = 'https://img.freepik.com/free-icon/volleyball-ball-outline_318-71525.jpg?size=338&ext=jpg';
  img.style.position = 'absolute';
  img.style.width = '60px';
  img.style.height = '60px';
  img.speed = 5;
  img.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerWidth) + 'px';
  document.body.appendChild(img);
  images.push(img);
}
setInterval(function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    const img = images[i];
    const rect = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (rect.top + rect.height > window.innerHeight || rect.top < 0) {
      img.speed *= -1;
    }
    img.style.top = rect.top + img.speed + 'px';
  }
}, 42);
```

```css
body {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<button id="but">create</button>
```

Comment: как сделать, чтобы при повторном нажатии на кнопку мячик не ускорялся ? Думала, очищать setInterval не помогает..

Comment: Поправил.......

Comment: Извините, я не правильно объяснила. Мне надо, чтобы каждый раз при нажатии на кнопку появлялась картинка и двигалась по вертикали с одной и той же скоростью

Comment: А в старом коде, при создании ещё одной картинки, она начинает двигаться быстрее. Вот

Comment: Еще раз поправил